# Using the <template></template> tag inside component template

Tags: vue.js

While working on a component that looks like this.

```
...
props: [
    'fType',
    'fName',
    'fChoiceValue',
],
template: `
    <template v-if="fType == ('text' || 'password')">
        <input v-bind:type="fType" v-bind:name="fName">
    </template>
`,
```

I discovered that vue would not render anything between the `<template>` tags. What is the proper way to do this without resorting to using `<span></span>` in place of `<template></template>`?

Answer (score 2):

Vue will warn you about this.

> Cannot use `<template>` as component root element because it may contain
>   multiple nodes.

That said, since you don't want to wrap, and borrowing from @Phil (the syntax in your question will always evaluate with `fType` equal to `text`), you can just render the input as the root.

```
template: `
  <input v-if="fType == 'text' || fType == 'password'" v-bind:type="fType" v-bind:name="fName">
`,
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/xdWmwO?editors=1010).

Comment: Unfortunately, vue did not throw any error in console. Hours later, I ran into the issue with 'text' || 'password' - I don't know what I was thinking;  and ended up using the lodash indexOf. Thanks.

Comment: @Dayo While you are developing, do not use the `min` version of Vue. That is the production version and it will not show the warnings in the console.

Comment: @Bert...thanks for the heads up. I now see all the warnings and errors.