# Template tag freezes browser when running site with webpack-dev-server

Tags: html, templates, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

We got Vue component split accross index.ts, template.html and style.css. When running site with webpack-dev-server and accessing this component through Chrome, the browser freezes. However if we replace **template tag** with **div tag** everything works. We are using webpack-dev-server v3.7.2

index.ts:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import axios from "../../../axios.js";
import Component from "vue-class-component";
require("./style.css")

@Component({
    name: "payment-type-card",
    template: require('./template.html')
})
export default class PaymentTypeCard extends Vue {
    ...
}
```

template.html:

```
<template>
  <div class="payment-type-card">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `template` tag cannot be used as component root element.

You have to use a standard HTML element

Comment: Could you please provide a link? I've been ggogling myself for hours, but was not able to find anything in relation to this question

Comment: @AntonMaiorov You can check this open issue on github: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5758

Comment: @AntonMaiorov there is also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927277/using-the-template-template-tag-inside-component-template